# Make a Discord Bot send a steam friend request

Tags: node.js, api, discord, steam

I have a Bot to check the CSGO ranks of members and give them a role on a discord server.

The bot wants to be added on steam right now. How can I make, that the bot steam account sends an request?

This is the code:

```
steamClient.on('friendRelationship', async (sid, relationship) => {
if (relationship === SteamUser.EFriendRelationship.Friend) { // If the relationship changes to "Friend" it means we are now friends
    // Find the user in our "onGoing" map
    var found = undefined;
    onGoing.forEach((value, key) => {
        if (value.steamid === sid.getSteamID64()) {
            found = {};
            found = { discord: key, steam: sid.getSteamID64(), channel: value.channel, message: value.message };
        }
    });
    if (found === undefined) { // This shouldn't really happen
        steamClient.removeFriend(sid);
        return;
    }
```